# Can Microsoft Word continue numbering different lists, such as Hierarchical headings?

Tags: microsoft-word

If I right-click "Continue Numbering" on "1. Tertiary heading", MS Word numbers it as C, not 1. Similarly, if I right-click "Continue Numbering" on "C. Another secondary heading", Word numbers it as 3, not C. I think you understand my issue? When I Googled this issue, I found [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/continue-numbering-from-earlier-list/8bcb5202-d458-4414-b45f-19f24005f199) advising "using the SEQ field code."  But this looks too complex to me! I'm computer illterate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [multilevel list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-new-bullets-numbers-and-multilevel-lists-6c06ef65-27ad-4893-80c9-0b944cb81f5f#multilevel) in Word. You may click Multilevel List button > Define New Multilevel List, then clear the box of "Enter formatting for number, choose the number style as following pictures for different levels.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And then you may apply the multilevel list, or you may change the list level for one heading.

[image]

Comment: See Shauna Kelly's page on this for step-by-step instructions. http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html ----- **Once you have this set up, do not use the buttons on the ribbon to change level! Apply the appropriate style instead.**